# Monero missing from pool payout to exchange wallet

Tags: transaction-confirmation, balance

I haven't found anyone having this problem. I setup Dwarfpool to payout to my exchange wallet. The payment never arrived. Here is my transaction ID:

```
0a5e6ba7332571b2e4258ec9e46d88307d26aaf0e7250812ec2b64b571b93a2c
```

And the display on a block explorer:

```
Timestamp: 0    Timestamp [UCT]: N/A    Age [y:d:h:m:s]:
Block: N/A  Fee (per_kB): 0.000031650000 (0.000018289842)   Tx size: 1.7305 kB
Tx version: 2   No of confirmations: 0  RingCT/type: yes/4
Extra: 0209010eda6590c24532c101239f2158a7bcc28e1fce9621f67340db8eb03bd47f5f76d6f26bcc8649de01e1
2 output(s) for total of ? xmr
stealth address amount  amount idx
00: 1e0828697af02dddbcd2536d5fb10ce05043065b8932239e43df47ff21bfa924    ?   N/A of 10958872
01: 517e9f04e298c5b7ee94129d8b72be7aefc9a1cadbd234fda9a7a2d959085b15    ?   N/A of 10958872
```

Comment: Can you post the transaction ID / hash. Also, to which exchange did you send it?

Comment: 0a5e6ba7332571b2e4258ec9e46d88307d26aaf0e7250812ec2b64b571b93a2c     Poloniex

Comment: I can confirm it's in the tx pool but it hasn't been mined. Nothing obvious as to why it's not been picked up (over a day old). There is another tx with the exact same age which makes me wonder if they are trying to spend the same inputs or something. You should contact the exchange I think because it looks like it's going to timeout/drop from the tx pool.

Comment: Has thus happen before? I have seen any issuse like this one. The funds will be returned to the starting wallet? It was a cash out from a mining pool

Comment: If you sent from the exchange, it shouldn't matter how it got deposited to the exchange. As I said, contact them, with as much detail as possible. It will get dropped from the tx pool if not mined. Max time in the tx pool is 3 days then it gets dropped. Funds reappear back in the senders wallet. But definitely contact them and show it's in the pool, unmined: https://xmrchain.net/txpool

Comment: It looks like it's been 3 days. And it's still there.

Comment: I have checked a number of different nodes and it is not present any more on those node tx pools, so not sure why xmrchain is holding it still. You still need to contact your exchange because the tx id you supplied was not mined. You can check other nodes tx pool like: `curl -X POST http://node.supportxmr.com:18081/get_transaction_pool | jq .transactions[].id_hash` and verify it's not been mined like: `curl -X POST http://node.supportxmr.com:18081/get_transactions -d '{"txs_hashes":["0a5e6ba7332571b2e4258ec9e46d88307d26aaf0e7250812ec2b64b571b93a2c"]}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'`

Comment: Ok I have emailed them what happened. I was mining on dwarfpool.
Idk how there pay out system works.
Does it time out after 7 days? I wondering if it will return to my pool balance.

Comment: Well this is new information. So you were mining on a pool with an exchange wallet as the payout destination? In this case, you need to contact the *pool*, not the exchange.

Comment: And no. Seeing as you are sending from a *pool*, not an exchange, it's unlikely the pool will correct your balance automatically. You will need to contact them.

Comment: Thanks you guys have been so helpful. Does a pool have a set adresses that is automates to pay out? I'm wondering how they will the amount? Like once it times out their balance will be higher?

Comment: You need to contact the pool.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take this up with the pool that sent your transaction and prove the tx was never mined.

You can check various nodes (https://moneroworld.com/#nodes), via the RPC interface, to prove the tx has not been mined by running the following from the command-line:

```
curl -X POST http://node.moneroworld.com:18089/get_transactions -d '{"txs_hashes":["0a5e6ba7332571b2e4258ec9e46d88307d26aaf0e7250812ec2b64b571b93a2c"]}' -H 'Content-Type: application/json'
```

For which you will get output like:

```
{
  "missed_tx": ["0a5e6ba7332571b2e4258ec9e46d88307d26aaf0e7250812ec2b64b571b93a2c"],
  "status": "OK",
  "untrusted": false
}
```

Which shows the tx is missing (`missed_tx`).

You can also prove it is not even waiting to be mined by showing that the tx is not even in the networks tx pool by running:

```
curl -X POST http://node.moneroworld.com:18089/get_transaction_pool | grep 0a5e6ba7332571b2e4258ec9e46d88307d26aaf0e7250812ec2b64b571b93a2c
```

Which will give no results.

Therefore, the pool needs to credit back your account.

Comment: Also block time is 7 days? I heard 3 but it's well over that. 7 seems to be what most older posts say.

Comment: The tx pool holds transactions for up to 3 days. Or if the tx is in an alternative block (orphaned), 7 days.